# What is relation of job target and nonce in pool mining

Tags: mining, mining-pools, pool-mining, research

When I was reading some miner code I saw a piece and found it was related to the nonce's value, but I was not able find out whether it is proportional or not. If not, then what is it's relation to the nonce's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is relation of job target and nonce in pool mining

The *job target* is the level of difficulty the miner produced hash must meet to be accepted by the pool.

The *nonce* is a miner supplied piece of data to include in what it hashes. Every time the nonce is changed the resulting hash is different, hence the miner keeps changing the nonce till it finds a hash that meets the job difficulty target.

> but I was not able find out whether it is proportional or not

They are *not* proportional.

Comment: Is there any function which gives their relation

Comment: They are only related insofar as you get a different hash if you change the nonce. This is because if you change the input data to a hash function, you get a different hash.

Comment: Can I get the research paper from mrl or bit monero research lab on this

Comment: Teaching people how mining works is not within the remit of MRL. I suggest you review miner / pool source code (most are open source), and review Q/As [tagged "mining"](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining) on this SE.